# setting default value for option in html

Tags: html

I have the following html code for  yes as default value on page load. but it is not reflecting on the page.

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
    <label for="headoffice" class="col-sm-6 col-xs-7 col-md-4 col-lg-4 control-label">Head Office Member<sup class="text-red">*</sup></label>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8">                  
        <select class="multi-select" id="headoffice" name="headoffice" data-placeholder="Head Office Member">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="No" selected="selected">No</option>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option> 
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where's the HTML Code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the given HTML code, you have given *selected="selected"* for the "No" option. You need to give that in "Yes" option as follows.

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
    <label for="headoffice" class="col-sm-6 col-xs-7 col-md-4 col-lg-4 control-label">Head Office Member<sup class="text-red">*</sup></label>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8">                  
        <select class="multi-select" id="headoffice" name="headoffice" data-placeholder="Head Office Member">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="No" >No</option>
            <option value="Yes" selected="selected">Yes</option> 
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```